# In django if I have more than one database , how do I tell django to create which model-table in which database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-database

For example I have these two databases. Now while creating a model class, how do I tell django to initiate that model table in the  'movie' database and not in the 'default' one.

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'projectInfo',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '123@abc',
    
        },
        'movie': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'movieDB',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '123@abc',
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: With a router: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a [database router [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers). This specifies, based on the model to what database it should route. For example if you want to route the `movie.Movie` model in the `movie` model, you use:

```
class MyRouter:
    special_routing = {
        'movie.Movie': 'movie'
    }

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return self.special_routing.get(model._meta.label)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return self.special_routing.get(model._meta.label)

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return self.special_routing.get(obj1._model._meta.label) == self.special_routing.get(obj2._model._meta.label)

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return db == self.special_routing.get(f'{app_label}_{model_name}', 'default')
```

Then we can add this to the [**`DATABASE_ROUTERS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE_ROUTERS):

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MyRouter']
```

You can write a more sophisticated router that thus will hint to what database to write.